# Javascript PrintScreen

Tags: javascript

Javascript from client side.

That is the window.clipBoard in javascript i got some documents where text copied to clipboard is got and shown.

I want the to implement the "PrintScreen" functionality over a web application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick google search to check, no you cannot make screenshots with javascript. You will need to use a different language and if you want to put in a webpage then the user will be prompted for extra privilages. Additionally, window.clipBoardData only works in ie.

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()`  ??