# Getting a PrintScreen of Client PC over Web Application

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to get "PrintScreen" of Client PC when he access a particular Web Page.

I tried GOOGLEing this IDEA! but was unable to get much,

Infact what i got know on stackoverflow itself is [Javascript PrintScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606108/javascript-printscreen)

JavaScript cannot be used for such functionality.

So, I would like to know can it be done in Ajax,ASP.NET with C#/VB or in PHP
because at the end i want to save this image/s continously to database either SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle.

Is this feasible by ActiveX Objects?

To my knowledge, it will be difficult to go ahead with javascript.Yet i plan to use more of client resourses than server resources while executing this functionality.

Comment: This sounds like privacy invasion to me

Comment: yea i agree to the above..why would you want to store printscreens of client pcs? what can you possibly gain from it?

Comment: I think you would have to create an ActiveX control to install from your webpage to call into the Windows API and call the 'Print Screen' function. I actually hope this isn't possible with recent browsers.

Comment: Just like we have screen recoder or capture apps which captures every activity on screen to a video which is saved to a drive/disk. Similarly i want to have the "same" thing for a web app.

Comment: suspecting malicious program........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not have access to client computer resources. What you describe there can't be achieved without a third party dll (if you mentioned .Net) installed on your computer and that can be done only on demand by the client. But the whole idea is, as stated before a privacy invasion and any attempt to install anything on the client computer will be regarded as a security threat from any AV software.

Comment: +1: If someone ever figures out how to do this, I hope they go directly to jail.

Comment: well if they will do it will be a major security breach; however a lot of people click yes without reading what the computer warns them ... so there is a way and also it's an easy one :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply NOT Possible by the why you need this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "JavaScript cannot be used for such functionality" before. But since you have figure it out, I can tell you that ASP.NET can't help you on this if JS can't. Because all ASP.NET at client side is javascript. Ajax things are actually working through javascript. ASP.NET just generates those javascripts for you to make your code working like a WebForm.